# Chrome extension action.onClicked

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am building a  chrome extension and I use this code to open the popup in new window. (Using manifest v3) It suddenly stopped working today.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onClicked')
Yesterday it worked just fine and it corresponds with chrome extension documentation. Anyone knows what the issue could be?

Here is my code:

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(tab => {
    chrome.windows.create({
        url: chrome.runtime.getURL("popup.html"),
        type: "popup",
        height: 800,
        width: 516
      }, function(win) {
      });
});
```

Comment: It means you're either loading this script as a content script (a mistake) or you've deleted `action` section from your manifest.json.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This question was already answered, but I wanted to post a full example since I couldn't find a post that had both extension code and corresponding manifest.json.

Here is full, valid example using Manifest V3.

```
// File: manifest.json //

{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "My extension",
    "description": "Extension that extends things",
    "author": "Me",
    "version": "0.1",
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": [
          "https://*"
        ],
        "js": ["content.js"]
      }
    ],
    "icons": { "48":  "icons/icon128.jpg",
              "128":  "icons/icon512.jpg"},
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "action": {},
    "permissions": [
      "storage",
      "downloads",
      "tabs"
  ]
}
```

```
// File: background.js //

// Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(tab => {
    // Send a message to the active tab
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
      var activeTab = tabs[0];
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {"message": "clicked_browser_action"});
    });
  });
```

(Obviously remove the comment from the .json file before copying it, and adjust the permissions of your extension appropriately.)

Note that if you're using a version of Chrome below Chrome 93, your manifest.json and background.js must be in the SAME directory.