# Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

There are plenty of issues open on the subject, but I couldn't find an explanation in my case. Here is a minimal test case:

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Button Click",  
    "description": "Be able to press buttons",  
    "version": "1.0",    
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
     },
    "action": { 
        "default_icon": "icons/bypass.png"
    },
    "host_permissions": [
        "*://*/*"
      ],    
    "permissions": ["debugger", "storage", "scripting", "nativeMessaging"]
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    console.log('clicked');
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        var activeTab = tabs[0];
        chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
            (request, sender, senderResponse) => { console.log('listener') }

        );
        
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {"message": "run"});
    });
});
```

As far as I can tell, the listener is set once the extension icon is clicked and a message is immediately sent straight after. Does anyone know why the listener doesn't seem to pick up the message?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't look like you have all the required permissions. Does this answer your question? [Chrome extension action.onClicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69296754/chrome-extension-action-onclicked)

Comment: Your onMessage listener is in the background script context, but you need a listener in the content script, which you can inject using chrome.scripting API.

Comment: @wOxxOm But can't the onMessage listener be in the background script context? Does it have to be in the content script?

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski I've tried adding the "tabs" and "runtime" permissions, but the problem persists.

Comment: It can't. You're sending the message to the tab, meaning you must use a content script in the tab. The background script doesn't run in the tab, it runs in its own context.